# Bootstrap 5 text BEFORE switch-checkbox (without extra addons/plugins)

Tags: checkbox, switch-statement, bootstrap-5

I use Bootstrap 5 and I wand to use a switch-toggle.

I don't want to use any other addons, but only with bootstrap.

How to put a Text BEFORE the toggle switch.

This does not work:

```
<div class="form-check form-switch">
  off
  <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="site_state">
  <label for="site_state" class="form-check-label">on</label>
</div>
```

Anyone have an idea ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What if you put your Off label before the checkbox and make everything `display: inline-block`?

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="d-inline-block me-1">Off</div>
            <div class="form-check form-switch d-inline-block">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="site_state" style="cursor: pointer;">
                <label for="site_state" class="form-check-label">On</label>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi.
Of course, I also thought of "d-inline-block" first, but I hadn't thought of constructing a complete scaffolding around it.
But the solution works and I would like to thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

You could wrap it in a `d-flex`..

```
<div class="d-flex">
    off
    <div class="form-switch ms-2">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="site_state">
    </div>
    <label for="site_state" class="form-check-label">on</label>
</div>
```

[Demo](https://www.codeply.com/p/BIXQkD77C4)

Comment: Any advantage of this over the accepted answer?

Answer (score 2):

bootstrap 5.3

form-check-reverse exchanges the positions of label and input;
form-check-inline clears the padding/margin;

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
      <div class="form-check form-check-inline form-check-reverse">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault">Label on the left</label>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault">Label on the right</label>
      </div>
```